# Showing $\phi$ is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

Took an exam with the following question (which I'm sure I did not answer correctly) but I believe I'll get some partial credit:

Let $\phi:C[-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $\phi(f)=f(0)+f(1/2)$ for each continuous function $f$.

A) Show that $\phi$ is linear.

B) Show that $\phi$ is continuous if the supremum norm, $||f||_{\infty}=sup\{|f(t)|: t \in [-1,1] \}$ is used on $C[-1,1]$. (The norm on $\mathbb{C}$ is absolute value).

C) Find a constant $B$ such that $||\phi||_{op} \le B$ ($||\phi||_{op}$ is the "operator" or "functional" norm of $\phi$.

**My approach on the test:**

**A** was easy and straightforward.

I noticed there is a relation between problem B and C. I basically started by saying that $\phi$ will be continuous if and only if $\phi$ is bounded. So I tried bounding it (although I'm not good at bounding things). Here's what I did:

$$\left |\phi \right|=\left |f(0)+f(1/2) \right |$$ Since $f$ is continuous then $|f(t)| \le B$ for some $B \in \mathbb{C}$ and some $t \in [-1,1]$. Then I somehow concluded that $$\left |\phi \right|=\left |f(0)+f(1/2) \right | \le B ||f||$$ which simultaneously answers part C. The whole problem is worth 20 points. I'm sure I'm only getting barely half if I'm lucky since I know I did part A correctly. How does one bound this problem correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in C[-1,1]$, then $$|\phi(f)|=|f(0)+f(1/2)|\leq|f(0)|+|f(1/2)|\leq 2\|f\|_{\infty},$$
by definition of the supremum norm. Hence, $B=2$ does the job and shows that $\phi$ is a bounded (and hence continuous) operator.

Comment: I would have never figured that out. But does half credit seem fair at least? lol

Comment: I guess it depends on your instructor and on how much weight was given to B and C.